# How to reuse a Process instance with slightly different ProcessStartInfo instances?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, robocopy

I have the following code that starts [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) as a `Process`. I also need to do database queries to determine which directories I need to copy each time `robocopy` is called so I used `ProcessStartInfo` to control the arguments passed.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<ProcessStartInfo> processInfos = GetProcessInfos(context, args[0]);
            foreach (ProcessStartInfo processInfo in processInfos)
            {
                // How can I reuse robocopy Process instances and
                // how can I dispose of them properly?
                Process.Start(processInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ProcessStartInfo> GetProcessInfos(MyDbContext context,
                                                                 string directory)
    {
        const string defaultRobocopyFormatString = "{0} {1} /mir /tee /fft /r:3 /w:10 /xd *Temp*";
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        return from dir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories()
               from myEntity in context.MyEntities
               where dir.Name == myEntity.Name
               select new ProcessStartInfo("robocopy", 
                                           string.Format(defaultRobocopyFormatString,
                                                         Path.Combine("C:\Test", dir.Name), 
                                                         Path.Combine("C:\Test_bak", dir.Name)));
    }
}
```

How can I reuse `Process` instances returned by the `static` `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` inside the `foreach` loop and how can I `Dispose` of them properly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reusing" the `Process` instances? You can dispose of them properly by calling `Dispose` (or using `using`)...

Comment: @vesan To my understanding, `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` will start a new `Process` every time it is called, I want only one `robocopy` process to be running with different arguments passed into it, is that possible?

Comment: Unless `robocopy` (I'm not very familiar with it) itself supports multiple argument sets being passed in, then you have to start a new process for each iteration.

Comment: I'm fairly certain what you're seeking won't work unless you're only launch command shell. In which case you only need to write to stdin and it'll work like typing in the shell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot re-use a Process object.  The Process class behaves like all of the other .NET classes that wrap an operating system object.  Like Socket, Bitmap, Mutex, FileStream, etcetera.  They are tiny little cookies that are very cheap to bake and take very little space on the GC heap.  They track the lifetime of the underlying OS object carefully, once the object is dead, the .NET wrapper object is no longer useful either.

The Process class signals that the cookie was eaten with its Exited event and HasExited property.  It has some post-bite properties that are useful, ExitCode and ExitTime.

But that's where it ends, if you want to create another process then you have to bake another cookie.  Simple to do with the *new* keyword or the Start() factory function.  Don't try to optimize it, there's no point and it can't work.  Re-using ProcessStartInfo is fine, it is not a wrapper class.

Comment: Nice answer with explanation about the internals of `Process`. Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify some official documentation proof that Process instance cannot be reused? My experiments on .Net 5 (Debian) show the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to reuse the `Process` class - that's just a wrapper for the underlying process. And when processes end, they're gone, completely - that's the main point of having a process in the first place.

Instead, it seems like you really want to just make sure that only one of those `robocopy` processes runs at a time, which is pretty easy:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    IEnumerable<ProcessStartInfo> processInfos = GetProcessInfos(context, args[0]);
    foreach (ProcessStartInfo processInfo in processInfos)
    {
        using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
        {
            // Blocks until the process ends
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        // When the `using` block is left, `process.Dispose()` is called.
    }
}
```