# Open a process, get the output, then open another process and get output

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, io-redirection

I'm trying to write a simple vb program to sync standard input/output to a textbox. The program should first locate an exe file, then run the file and get output to the textbox, then close the file, then either re-run the file or run another file. Things work out fine the first time, however when I close the file and try to re-run, I can no longer get the output. Please let me know what's wrong. Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim P As New Process
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter
Dim fd As New OpenFileDialog
Dim progName As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
    P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    P.SynchronizingObject = TextBox1

    fd.Title = "Open Program"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\windows\system32"
    fd.Filter = "EXE program | *.exe"
    fd.FilterIndex = 1
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayOutput(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal output As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    TextBox1.AppendText(output.Data() & vbCrLf)
End Sub

Private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Static Line As String

    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Return) Then

        SW.WriteLine(Line & vbCrLf)

        Line = ""

    Else

        Line = Line & e.KeyChar

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OpenFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenFile.Click
    If fd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        progName = fd.FileName
        TextBox1.AppendText(progName & vbCrLf)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonRun.Click

    ButtonRun.Enabled = False
    ButtonStop.Enabled = True

    AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    AddHandler P.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    P.StartInfo.FileName = progName
    P.Start()

    P.BeginOutputReadLine()

    SW = P.StandardInput
    SW.WriteLine()

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonStop.Click
    ButtonStop.Enabled = False
    ButtonRun.Enabled = True
    P.CancelOutputRead()
    RemoveHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    RemoveHandler P.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    ''P.CloseMainWindow()
    P.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate you're process instance every time you want to run a program since [`Process` objects cannot be reused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30298281/4295017).

So, define `P` as

```
Dim P As Process    ' Notice no `new` here
```

and move its initialization code from `Form1_Load` to `ButtonRun_Click`:

```vb
Private Sub ButtonRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonRun.Click

    ButtonRun.Enabled = False
    ButtonStop.Enabled = True

    ' vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    P = new Process
    P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
    P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    P.SynchronizingObject = TextBox1
    ' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    AddHandler P.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    P.StartInfo.FileName = progName
    P.Start()

    P.BeginOutputReadLine()

    SW = P.StandardInput
        SW.WriteLine()

End Sub
```